# Custom Column(s) with MsSqlServer Sink and AppSettings

Tags: c#, sql-server, serilog

I've got an application that runs without problem with the File and Console Sinks and now I'm trying to add the MSSqlServer Sink.

Looking at the documentation on [Github](https://github.com/serilog-mssql/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver) I've got my application to write to the SQL Database as well as the other sinks.

```
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.connectionString" value="Server=servername;Database=databasename;User Id=userid;Password=password;"/>
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.tableName" value="Logs"/>
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.autoCreateSqlTable" value="true"/>
```

One improvement is I'd like to add a custom column to the Logs table that Serilog uses to store a number indicating a unique RunId for my application. The idea being that a simple query would allow grouping by RunId to see all messages for that one run.

So I added the following, based on the documentation (and I haven't been able to find any other examples) as it seemed logical:

```
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.columnOptions.ColumnName" value="RunId"/>
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.columnOptions.PropertyName" value="RunId"/>
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.columnOptions.DataType" value="SqlDbType.Int"/>
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.columnOptions.DataLength" value="32"/>
```

and then in my code all I need to do is:

```
    Log.Information("{RunId}{Message}", RunId, Message);
```

to see a new entry with {RunId} in the RunId column and {Message} in the Message column... however everytime I do this nothing is written to the RunId column, it remains as NULL whereas every log message the console/file has is also duplicated in the Table.

So it seems logging is working, it must be the keys wrong and I'm really not sure what should be used.

Would anyone be able to point me in the direction I need to be going or where I've gone wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Logging definitely was working but some digging and finally I found out I had two issues:

1. Permissions on database where insuffident for the user serilog was using, and
2. AppSettings settings I was using were wrong

#1 was easy enough to fix, I created a dedicated Serilog account for this database and fixed the permissions as per [documentation](https://github.com/serilog-mssql/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#permissions).

#2 however was very frustrating but eventually I was able to get the following to work:

```
    <configSections>
    <section name="MSSqlServerSettingsSection" type="Serilog.Configuration.MSSqlServerConfigurationSection, Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer"/>
</configSections>
<MSSqlServerSettingsSection DisableTriggers="false" ClusteredColumnstoreIndex="false" PrimaryKeyColumnName="Id">
    <!-- SinkOptions parameters -->
    <TableName Value="Logs"/>
    <Columns>
        <add ColumnName="RunId" DataType="int"/>
    </Columns>
</MSSqlServerSettingsSection>
```

On compile and execution my program will now create the Logs table in the database and then create a RunId column which I have been able to populate with a {RunId} expression in my Log.Debug() calls.

FWIW: I hope this will be helpful and if I can work out how I'll see if I can add this to documentation as an example of using AppSettings for this use case. Searching this question most people seem to be using JSON and not AppSettings.